# How to Convert Folder to rar File using C#?

Tags: c#

In This Method Finally after saving the File Path I have to Copy the same File and i need to move to another place and i need to make that file as a Rar file How to Do this?

```
public JsonResult UploadResume(HttpPostedFileBase resume)
    {
        if (resume != null)
        {
            string Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(resume.FileName);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Resume/0");
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(resume.FileName);

            DirectoryInfo di = null;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, 0 + extension);
            resume.SaveAs(filepath);
        }
        return Json(new { result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Execute `rar.exe` using `Process.Start()` and specify the correct parameters.

Comment: Particularly notice *"As the RAR compression algorithm **isn't free** (only the decompression algorithm is), you won't find a library for it (or have to purchase a license)."*

Comment: I would better use Zip format, is more standard between different OSes, and use the DotNetZipLib, it's a very good library.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sFileToZip = @"C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\Stuff\text1.txt";
            string sZipFile = @"C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\Stuff\text1.zip";

            using (FileStream __fStream = File.Open(sZipFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                GZipStream obj = new GZipStream(__fStream, CompressionMode.Compress);

                byte[] bt = File.ReadAllBytes(sFileToZip);
                obj.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);

                obj.Close();
                obj.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/517141/Howplustopluscompressplusdirectory-2cplusMakeplusR)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of third party library that will compress the files into RAR format, or execute a command line tool (like RAR.EXE) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Get a rar utility ([WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/), [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or sth else) and start it from your code

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStart(pathToMyUtility, arguments);
```

and that's it.